# Toggling the opacity of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to write a code that toggles the opacity of a div but I'm running into trouble with it. If I click this button, I want it to set the opacity of #infodiv to 1.0, where it's set at 0.0 right now, like so.

```
#infodiv{
    width: 250px;
    height: 0px;
    margin-top: 10%;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
```

This is the function that I'm trying to call.

```
function toggles(){
    infodiv.css('opacity', '1.0');
}
```

It's probably the function that it's need of some tweaking, maybe? Thanks to anyone willing to take a look to help out. Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/re1uzse4/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gzntu28d/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set style of element with jQuery:

```
function toggles() {
  $('#infodiv').css('opacity', '1.0');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use pure javascript, your function will be look like that

```
function toggles(){
   document.getElementById('infodiv').style.opacity = '1.0';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

```js
var infodiv = document.querySelector("#infodiv");

function clickToggle(){
   this.classList.toggle("active")
}

infodiv.addEventListener("click",clickToggle, false);
```

```css
#infodiv{
width: 250px;
height: 250px;
background: red;
opacity: 1;
}
#infodiv.active{opacity: 0}
```

```html
<div id=infodiv></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use with [ID selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) which returns a jQuery object as the method [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) is a jQuery function

```
function toggles() {
  $('#infodiv').css('opacity', '1.0');
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gzntu28d/)

However I would recommend you to create a CSS class like

```
.higheropacity {
    opacity: 1.0 !important
}
```

Then use `.toggleClass()` method

```
function toggles() {
  $('#infodiv').toggleClass('higheropacity');
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L85vmoLj/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to toggle whether something is displayed in jQuery is with `.toggle()`

```
$('#infodiv').click(function(){
   $(this).toggle();
})
```

if you need to change opacity then try `toggleClass()` and create a new CSS class that has opacity 1

```
// CSS

.opaque{
   opacity: 1;
}

// jQuery

$('#infodiv').click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('opaque');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
      $('#infodiv').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
#infodiv {
  width: 250px;
  margin-top: 10%;
  opacity: 0.0;
}
#infodiv.active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="infodiv">
  <div class="infotext">This is a test.</div>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn">btn</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, besides the jQuery one, you can always do something like

```
function toggles() {
   document.getElementById('infodiv').style.opacity = 1;
}
```

if you feel like using pure javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a function?
Why not use:

```js
 $('#infodiv').toggle();
```

From the api - "The .toggle() method animates the width, height, and opacity of the matched elements simultaneously."